# Таблицы с большим количеством атрибутов в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, erlang

Для реализации алгоритма классификации web страниц необходимо эти страницы представлять в виде массива. Одна запись в массиве выглядит так:

"Слово" => "Количество повторов".

В итоге получается массив размерами от 5к до 25к элементов.
Хотел хранить так:

```
{url: "ссылка", "слово1": 10, ... , "словоN": 9999}
```

но почему-то такие большие записи не сохраняются. В чем может быть проблема?

Для выгрузки страниц и разбиения на слова использую Erlang, драйвер монги: https://github.com/SergejJurecko/erlmongo

Но ничего не сохраняется, возвращается результат типа:

```
{oid,<<"0001c5674c7b893dc4000001">>}
```

И при этом в самой базе пусто. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте внимательно лимиты [монги](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/). Возможно Вы где то в них упираетесь.  А вообще, нужно больше информации. Попробуйте собрать весь json и через mongo shell залить его, может будет внятная ошибка.